# Permutations on four consecutive digits yield $n$ such that $2013 < n < 10000$

Tags: combinatorics

2013 is the first year since the Middle Ages that consists of four consecutive digits. How many
such years are there still to come after 2013 (and before the year 10000)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: The possible sets of four consecutive digits are $\{0,1,2,3\}$, $\{1,2,3,4\}$, $\{2,3,4,5\}$, and so on up through $\{6,7,8,9\}$. For each of these sets of four digits you should determine how many different years the set can give you after $2013$. The sets whose smallest elements are bigger than $1$ are easiest, because they can’t give you any years at or before $2013$. You’ll have to work a little harder with the first two sets.